# Look at the given definition of monomorphism and try to formulate the definition of epimorphism

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> A function $f : A \to B$ is a monomorphism (or monic) if the following holds:
>   for all sets $Z$, and all functions $\alpha', \alpha'': Z \to A: f\alpha' =f\alpha'' \implies \alpha' = \alpha''.$

$f: A \to B$ is epimorphism if for all sets $Z$ and for all functions $b: Z \to B$, there's a function $a: Z \to B$ such that  $fa = b$.

I realize this definition looks too much like that of surjection, but I am not sure what else I could do. Please, help me fix it.

Comment: Epimorphisms *are* kind of a generalization of surjections. What information were you given about the relationship between epimorphisms and monomorphisms? Were you told they were dual or...?

Comment: The above definition of monomorphism is given and a proposition that goes "a function is injective iff it's monomorphism" is proven. We are asked to do the same for epimorphism and surjection.

Comment: I see. All I can say without completely giving it away is that the definition should look very similar to the one of monomorphisms; try drawing some diagrams and reversing arrows. Maybe someone here can give you a better hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition you have given is the definition of a *split epimorphism*.  In the category of sets:

- A function is a split epimorphism if and only if is a surjection (one direction is the axiom of choice).
- A function is a surjection if and only if it is an epimorphism.

Therefore, over the category of sets, epimorphisms and split epimorphisms are the same thing.  However, the two definitions are not equivalent in general.

I don't quite understand the question you've been asked, so I'll just tell you that the correct definition of an epimorphism is exactly dual to the definition of a monomorphism; so you should take the definition of a monomorphism and reverse the arrows and the direction of composition in order to arrive at the definition of an epimorphism.  Then prove that your definition is equivalent to surjectivity.